# Azure Data Factory unable to output JSON data

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

Hi I am working in azure data factory. I am trying to construct dynamic json object as below.

json('{"fullName": "Sophia Owen"}') This results in

```
{
  "fullName": "Sophia Owen"
}
```

this works but when I do

`@json('{"fullName":@{pipeline().parameters.UserId}}')` this results in

```
"json('{\"fullName\":myname@mydomain.com}')"
```

Any idea how can I get

```
{
  "fullName": "myname@mydomain.com"
}
```

any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below expression and it worked fine.

```
@json(concat('{"key": "', pipeline().parameters.UserId, '"}'))
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. After 48 hours, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, 
I have the same problem with a json string when I sink it into cosmos.
I can't find the @json function. I am trying to use it in expression builder of a derived column but there is nothing like json function. Could you please tell me where do you call this function ?
Thnks